# Error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying a simple sign in application using Spring-Mvc by referring  [this url](http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/29799/simple-login-web-application-using-spring-mvc-spring-security-and-spring-jdbc). But while doing this I am getting following error:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select username,password from users where username=?]; The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

The only change that I did in the program is changing query in spring-security file from and to are mentioned here:

original:

```
<authentication-provider>
       <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
           users-by-username-query="select username,password from users where username=?"
           authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from users where username=?" />
   </authentication-provider>
```

changed:

```
<authentication-provider>
       <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
           users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from users where username=?"
           authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from users where username=?" />
   </authentication-provider>
```

I don't have any enabled field in my users table. So I removed it. I am using PostgreSQL database. The example given in the url is using oracle/mysql database.

Is 'enabled'  any inbuilt field or keyword in oracle? If yes then what is the replacement for it in PostgreSQL database.

Comment: can you edit which postgres qyery using

Comment: @Shubhambatra The query mentioned  in second code part is used